# Should chat be distinguished from discussion?

Tags: discussion

Chat is people hanging around in a room.

Discussion is what is prompted by a question. However they're turfed into chat.

If the points discussed are worthwhile it seems worth keeping them tied with the question that prompted them.

Plus it allows one to go away and think about what is said and come back with a response - whereas chat is immediate.

Presumably SE pushes discussion into chat so that discussion doesn't clutter up the Question, but if discussions can be 'rolled up' I don't see why that should be a problem.

If the discussion is long, can one use 'data' techniques to trim out what looks like lo-value stuff; and perform other house-keeping devices?

Comment: You can create separate chatrooms for specific discussion if you prefer. And while chat is "instant", you are under no pressure to respond immediately. Just say you need to think about it and respond later... I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I was thinking out aloud. I've noticed that other people on meta have asked the same question.